# Script for redactor.js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, redactor

I try to create a simple test-Script in Jsfiddle for a external Script (redactor.js), but it doesn't work :-(

```
if (typeof RedactorPlugins === 'undefined') var RedactorPlugins = {};

RedactorPlugins.advanced = {
    init: function () {
        alert(1);
    }
}

$('#article').redactor({
    plugins: ['advanced']
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/DEYx7/
I don't get the alert...

But I don't know, what I'm doing wrong, cause that is a quite simple example and it should work...

The Example-Code of the external redactor.js-Script: http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/plugins-creating/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define your plugin **first**, and make the plugin object globally available. Please see the [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DEYx7/1/):

```
if (typeof RedactorPlugins === 'undefined') window.RedactorPlugins = {};

RedactorPlugins.advanced = {
    init: function () {
        alert(1);
    }
}
$.getScript("http://imperavi.com/js/redactor/redactor.js",function(){
    $('#article').redactor({
        plugins: ['advanced']
    });   
});
```

I removed the redactor.js script from the automatically loaded scripts, in order to execute your plugin definition first.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried to add a simple button for the script, but this fails in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DEYx7/2/

Comment: @user3142695 it does work, but you didn't assign any stile information (image) using CSS, and there is no image for a 'box' button - so the button is just invisible. You could reuse an existing image, though (see [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DEYx7/3/))